Conjectured stronger form of the triangle inequality $a^{\frac{R\log 4}{R\log 4-r}}+b^{\frac{R\log 4}{R\log 4-r}}\ge c^{\frac{R\log 4}{R\log 4-r}}$
Let $a \le b \le c$ be the sides of a triangle, $R$ be the circumradius and $r$ be the inradius. On the one hand, the triangle inequality says that $a+b \ge c$ with equality holding only in case of a degenerate triangle; on the other hand, for Pythagorean triplets, $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. This implies that for non-degenerate triangles, there is an $f(a,b,c) > 1$ such that $a^x + b^x \ge c^x$.
Trivially for any $0 \le x \le 1$, we have $a^x + b^x \ge c^x$; but the inequality fails when $x > 1$ is fixed, so we cannot strengthen the triangle inequality for an fixed exponent $x > 1$. However there may exist a variable $x = f(a,b,c) \ge 1$ such that $a^x + b^x \ge c^x$. Experimental data supports the following conjecture with variable exponent $\displaystyle x = 1 + \frac{r}{R\log 4}$.
Stronger form of the triangle inequality.
Let $x = 1 + r/(R\log 4)$. Then $a^x + b^x \ge c^x$, with equality holding only in case of a degenerate triangle. Here $\log 4$ is the optimal constant, and inequality fails for any lesser constant.
Update 12-Nov-2024: Data suggests exponent can be increased to
$$
x = 1 + \frac{r}{R\log 4} + \left(\frac{r}{R\log 4}\right)^2 
+ \left(\frac{r}{R\log 4}\right)^3 + \cdots = \frac{R\log 4}{R\log 4 - r}.
$$
Hence the triangle inequality is equivalent to
$$
a^{(R\log 4)/(R\log 4 - r)} + b^{(R\log 4)/(R\log 4 - r)} 
\ge c^{(R\log 4)/(R\log 4 - r)}. \tag 2
$$
Update 14-Nov-2024: Data suggest that the exponent can be further increased. There is a constant $\alpha \approx 4.79763515$ such that, if
$$
x = \max\left\{\frac{R\log 4}{R\log 4 - r}, 
\left(\frac{a+b-c}{R}\right)^\alpha \right\}, \tag 3
$$
then $a^x + b^x \ge c^x$.
In all the above, since $x \ge 1$, then, if true, the formulations strengthen the triangle inequality. Can they be proved or disproved?
Related: Root of the equation $a^x + b^x = c^x$ for triangle with sides $a ,b,c$

Is there any intuition as to why the constant should be $\log 4?$

@AdamRubinson $\log 4$ came entire out of experiments rather than intuition and also seemed to be the optimal constant

First, the inequality is only interesting when $c = \max\{a,b,c\} >a,b.$ Next, some standard formulae give us:
$$d=\dfrac rR = \dfrac{4S^2}{pabc}=\dfrac{4(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}{abc}.$$
Next, imagine the triangle $\triangle'$ with sides $\dfrac{a+b}{2}, \dfrac{a+b}{2},c$ and compute the same ratio:
$$d'=\dfrac{r'}{R'} = \dfrac{4\left(p-\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^2(p-c)}{\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^2c}\implies$$
$$\dfrac{d}{d'} = \dfrac{(a+b)^2(p-a)(p-b)}{ab(2p-a-b)^2}=\dfrac{(2z+x+y)^2xy}{(z+x)(z+y)(x+y)^2}\leq 1$$
with the Ravi substitution: $a=y+z, b=x+z, c=x+y.$
The last part can be proven very easily by expanding or observing the fact that the function $f(t) = \dfrac{(2t+x+y)^2}{(t+x)(t+y)}$ is decreasing in $t>0.$ What's this telling us is that when we move  $\triangle \to \triangle '$, $d\leq d'\iff x=\dfrac{1}{1-d/\log 4}\leq x'=\dfrac{1}{1-d'/\log4}.$ Therefore,
$$\left(\frac ac\right)^x+\left(\frac bc\right)^x\geq 2\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2c}\right)^x\geq 2\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2c}\right)^{x'}.$$
This means that if we can prove the inequality in the case of an isosceles triangle with the base being the largest side, then the general case follows. So now for simplicity and due to homogeneity, assume a triangle with sides $2,2, 2t$ with $1<t\leq 2$ and so $p=t+2$ and $d = \dfrac{4t^2(2-t)}{8t} = \dfrac{t(2-t)}{2}$ and $x = \dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{t(2-t)}{2\ln 4}}$ and the inequality is equivalent to:
$$2^{x+1}\geq 2^xt^x\iff \ln t\leq \dfrac{\ln 2}{x}=\ln2-\dfrac{t(2-t)}{4}.$$
But this seems trivial, since
$$\dfrac{\ln 2 - \ln t}{2-t} = \dfrac{d}{dt}(\ln t)\vert_{t=\theta}=\dfrac{1}{\theta}\geq \frac 12\geq \frac t4$$
due to $\theta,t\in (1,2].$
EDIT: To account for the revised question, the exact same method can be applied. The only requirement is that the new exponent $x'$ increases as we switch to an isosceles by doing $a,b \to \dfrac{a+b}{2}, \dfrac{a+b}{2}.$ Proof of this can be mimicked the corresponding part above - just show $R'\geq R.$
This being established, one can assume the same triangle $2,2, 2t$ with $1\leq t\leq 2$ and $x = \left((2-t)\sqrt{4-t^2}\right)^{\alpha}$, which gives the inequality to be satisfied:
$$\ln t\leq\dfrac{\ln 2}{\left((2-t)\sqrt{4-t^2}\right)^{\alpha}}\iff \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\leq\dfrac{\ln\ln 2 - \ln \ln t}{3\ln(2-t) + \ln(2+t)}.$$
I have no hope of finding the minimum of the RHS by hand and Wolfram does give us:
$$\dfrac{\alpha}{2} = \min\limits_{1\leq t\leq 2}\dfrac{\ln\ln 2 - \ln \ln t}{3\ln(2-t) + \ln(2+t)} = 2.39882.$$

@ dezdichado, is there a typpo in the exponent of the first term in the RHS of $$\left(\frac ac\right)^x+\left(\frac bc\right)^x\geq 2\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2c}\right)^x\geq 2\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2c}\right)^{x'}.$$ Also I am not clear how proving the inequality in the case of an isosceles triangle with the base being the largest side implies the general case.

@NilotpalSinha I don't think there is any typo there. Since $x\leq x'$ and $\frac{a+b}{2c}<1,$ increasing the exponent decreases the expression. Then we are proving $a'^{x'} + b'^{x'}\geq c^{x'},$ where $a',b'$ are $\frac{a+b}{2}, \frac{a+b}{2}$ and $x'$ is the corresponding exponent.
